# How to programmatically click element on DrawToolbar?

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

For some reason I would like to draw polygon using button but not the one from the Toolbar. In short, I want to click 'Click me!' button and start drawing polygon instead of choosing this option from toolbar. I tried to use jquery to trigger 'click' action on toolbar but can't do this at all. I noticed that 'buttons' on toolbar are not really `buttons` but simple classes. Maybe that's why I can't 'click' on them programatically. I also tried to use `observeEvent` but can't do this either. Do you have any idea how can I trigger this action?

Here's working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("btn", label = "Click me!"),
    leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    coords <- quakes %>%
        sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"), crs = 4326)

    output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
    leaflet::leaflet() %>% 
        leaflet::addTiles() %>% 
      leaflet::setView(172.972965,-35.377261, zoom = 4) %>%      
      leaflet::addCircleMarkers(
        data = coords,
        stroke = FALSE,
        radius = 6
        ) %>%         
      leaflet.extras::addDrawToolbar()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and here's my jQuery code which should trigger 'draw polygon' option on toolbar but is not working:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-polygon').click();
});
```

Comment: When is your jQuery code executed, compared to the code of the shiny app?

Comment: It's executed when I click 'Click me' button. I could also use `observeEvent` on this button but the problem is that neither jquery nor observeEvent trigger 'draw polygon' element. I have no idea how to do this, if you have please share your solution

Comment: I also checked this topic: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238528/how-to-enable-a-leaflet-draw-tool-programatically/238535#238535 but it doesn't work. Other jquery functions work properly in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue. In jQuery, instead of:

```
$('.leaflet-draw-draw-polygon').click();
```

there should be:

```
document.querySelector('.leaflet-draw-draw-polygon').click();
```

I don't know why the second one works and first one does not, they do the same job. Anyways, this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to happen when you click an `actionButton()` UI element, use `observeEvent()` to trigger code to run when the status of the button changes (when it's clicked, for example).  Something like this in your `server` code would probably work:

```
observeEvent(input$btn, {
  # the code you want to run when button is clicked
}
```

Comment: I know this:) but in this particular case I need to use jquery. But even if I used `observeEvent` to trigger 'draw polygon' action from toolbar I have no idea how to do this. I don't think it's possible. I could at best show/hide the whole toolbar using `observeEvent` but I guess I can't  do this for its element - 'draw polygon'